# MacPorts issue, "Error: Port aircrack not found" on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, macports

Using MacPorts 2.3.4 on OS X El Capitan, I get an error when issuing the following command:

```
sudo port install aircrack -g
```

I get the message, `Error: Port aircrack not found`.

I've updated the list of ports using, `port upgrade outdated`.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the *port* is "aircrack-ng", not "aircrack", and the *install* command is:

```
sudo port install aircrack-ng
```

Comment: I get `Error: Port aircrack-ng not found`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the full installation of Xcode and MacPorts command-line tools for your Mac version. Run Terminal.app, then run this command: `sudo port selfupdate`